# Proving Intervals with same Cardinality

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Using a diagram show intervals (0, 1) and (1, 3) have the same cardinality.

When I make the diagram only 1 is overlapped but because these are "(" and not "[" its exclusive so I don't see how the cardinality is the same in any way.

Comment: The cardinality of each interval is equivalent to the cardinality of $\mathbb R.

Comment: But how do we prove that?

Comment: What does it mean for two infinite sets to be equinumerous? (i.e., to have the same cardinality?).  Find a bijection from each interval to $\mathbb R$, or a bijection from $(0, 1)$ to $(1, 3)$.

Comment: Also, have you yet read my comment to your prior question: "You need to start including more context in your questions. You have asked a series of problem statement exercises that are not questions, but directives. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and abide by it, because you're no longer a "new contributor" and it's time you start trying to meet site expectations for posting acceptable questions."  Please do not abuse this site by mistaking it for a "homework completion" service.

Comment: I understand this, however, this is not "homework". What more context would you want me to add?

After reading the "How to ask a good question" most of it seems very useless, like what textbook did the question come from. None of my questions come from textbooks and I don't feel the need to add more content just for the sake of adding more content. I try and make my questions as concise as possible and add context like work showed when needed. Go back and review my "Good" questions and you will easily find I do this often.

I am sorry this question did not meet your expectations.